# Microsoft.Data AsNoTracking() for tracking SQL View updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for some way to get changes in SQL Server view to make a list of field name, original and new value. I'm using EF Core 3.1.0.

I was trying to do it using following packages:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

with something like `.Where().AsNoTracking()`, but it seems to be usable only with `System.Data.SqlData` instead.

The general flow is (at this moment as follows):

1. get original view
2. make update to the object view uses
3. SaveChangesAsync()
4. get updated view (this automatically sets to the original one, what is unexpected).

Some snipped/concept:

```
var originalView = dbContext.MyView.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
var updatedObject = dbContext.SomeTable.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
if (updatedObject = null) {
    throw;
}
updatedObject.SomeProperty = "New val";
await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
var updatedView = dbContext.MyView.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
dbContext.Entry(updatedView).Reload();
```

MyView contains i.a. fields from SomeTable. When accessing `updatedView`, either by FirstOrDefault() or by `dbContext.Entry().Reload()` - `originalView` and `updatedView` objects are equal (or updated or not yet)

Comment: Can you please show the actual code?

Comment: I cannot show actual code, but I can show some snippet/concept - I will add it to question.

Comment: @AluanHaddad any ideas?